# Removing Master pages to improve website performance

Tags: asp.net, architecture, web-architecture

I am thinking of improving the performance/user experience of our Asp.net Web Forms driven application. We have a aspx pages implementing a single master page. The layout of the master page is as follows:

[image]

Now the tree control on Area 1 is driving updates in Area 2 and Area 3. Based on the node of the tree different aspx pages are loaded. But that makes the whole page to reload which does not give a nice user experience.

I am thinking of getting rid of the master page and dynamically loading user controls in Area2 and Area3 using Update Panels based on the tree node selection.

Any recommendations please?

Comment: Try an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before giving up on master pages.

Comment: you will be basically turning this site into a Single Page Application. You should consider if this is a website or an application before drastic changes like this.

Answer (score 0):

Call that user controls dynamically with update panels, that ill do the trick. I just don't got why you need to get rid of the Master Page to achieve it.
As I see you just (maybe) don't need to instantiate that UCs when page starts. Anyway you ill "discard" that instances and recreate it (or just update that UCs data by ajax) when a node is selected.